# Distinct letters program, I don't understand the solution

Tags: c

I've been reading this code for the last 5 minutes and still could not understand what's the use of the `a[b]++;` line and the `if(a[i])` Here's the whole code

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    int a[0],i,p;
    char b;
    int main()
    {
        while(b!='}')
        {
            scanf("%c",&b);
            a[b]++;
        }
        for(i='a';i<='z';++i)
            if(a[i])
                p++;
            printf("%d",p);
     
        return 0;
    }
```

It's a program where it counts the number of distinct letters in an input. The input is basically a set of letters. They are separated by commas. E.g. {a, b, c}

Comment: You should not assume the code is correct. It has bugs resulting in Undefined Behaviour. For starters `int a[0]` is a zero length array so all the accesses to that array are UB.

Comment: @kaylum I'm assuming it is, since it's taken from the codeforces solutions in problem 443A. Also what is UB?

Comment: Undefined Behavior

Comment: codeforces is not God :-) The code is wrong.

Comment: Are you sure you copied it correctly? Maybe it was `int a[256] = {0};`

Comment: Yes, I'm sure I did. What would be the correct code then?

Comment: What I wrote would be correct.

Comment: The array contains counters for each character code. `b` is the code of the current input character, `a[b]++` adds 1 to it.

Comment: `if (a[i])` tests if `a[i]` is not 0. So it executes `p++` for every character that appeared at least once in the input. So that counts all the different letters that appeared.

Comment: Do you have a link to the solution (hopefully doesn't require registration).

Comment: I see, is it safe to assume that arrays are like lists in Python? Or at least have some similarities? Also here's the link to the specific solution https://codeforces.com/contest/443/submission/117981684 (No registration :D )

Comment: A better comparison would be to Python numpy arrays (which are implemented internally as C arrays).

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment, where you're supposed to identify the problems in the code and correct them.

Comment: @KenWhite I think the one who submitted the code probably didn't realize the mistake? Codeforces afaik only verifies the answer through test cases.

Comment: Did your compiler show some warning about that illegal array? If not, you might want to turn up warning level.

Answer (score 0):

This "solution" is full of bugs. However, you asked two specific questions, and these are answers:

> what's the use of the `a[b]++;` line?

The variable `b` holds the code of the character and is used as an index to the array `a`. The indexed cell of the array is incremented by the operator `++`. This way the numbers of distinct characters are found.

> what's the use of the `if(a[i])`?

In C, any non-zero (integer) expression is taken as "true". The condition here is true, if the cell of `a` indexed by `i` is not zero. `i` loops through the codes of 'a' to 'z'.